# how to start jrebel with jboss as 7

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jrebel

I do`not know how to use (configure) JRebel with Jboss as 7 (Bronthes).

First of all i am downloading plugin for eclipse next activate social license for JRebel.
Next use simple example Jboss gwt project : `gwt kitchensink`.

When i am running Jboss from eclipse console i have got info :

> Contacting myJRebel server .. [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  [2013-02-13
>   23:34:39]
>
> ####################################################### [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  JRebel 5.1.3
>
> (201302011417) [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  (c) Copyright ZeroTurnaround OU,
>   Estonia, Tartu. [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  Over the
>   last 1 days JRebel prevented  [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  at least 1
>   redeploys/restarts saving you about 0 hours. [2013-02-13 23:34:39] 
>   [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  This product is licensed to Lukasz Brudny
>   [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  License acquired through
>   myJRebel server. [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  You are
>   subscribed for the plan "JRebel Social Plan", [2013-02-13 23:34:39] 
>   subscription is for lifetime. [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  next license
>   check with the server is required by 2013-03-15. [2013-02-13 23:34:39]
>   [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  The following plugins are disabled at the
>   moment:  [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  * Camel plugin (set
>   -Drebel.camel_plugin=true to enable) [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  * Click plugin (set -Drebel.click_plugin=true to enable) [2013-02-13 23:34:39]
>   * JRuby Plugin (set -Drebel.jruby_plugin=true to enable) [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  * Jersey plugin (set -Drebel.jersey_plugin=true to enable)
>   [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  * Mustache Plugin (set
>   -Drebel.mustache_plugin=true to enable) [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  * Oracle ADF Core plugin (set -Drebel.adf_core_plugin=true to enable)
>   [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  * Oracle ADF Faces plugin (set
>   -Drebel.adf_faces_plugin=true to enable) [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  * RESTlet plugin (set -Drebel.restlet_plugin=true to enable) [2013-02-13
>   23:34:39]  * Seam-Wicket plugin (set -Drebel.seam_wicket_plugin=true
>   to enable) [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  * Spring Data Plugin (set
>   -Drebel.spring_data_plugin=true to enable) [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  * WebObjects plugin (set -Drebel.webobjects_plugin=true to enable)
>   [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  [2013-02-13 23:34:39]
>
> ####################################################### [2013-02-13 23:34:39]  23:34:39,592 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss
>
> Modules version 1.1.1.GA

i also have got checked checkbox `Build automatically`, and `Activate JRebel nature` on this project.

So what next ? JRebel add all Gwt stuff ? How i can deploy project to the server ? Using jboss plugin for eclipse or deploy via eclipse (run as --> Run on server) ??

Answer (score 1):

What you see is the JRebel banner, meaning you enabled JRebel for the runtime - that is just fine. When you enabled JRebel Nature, it should have generated a config file - rebel.xml - check that it exists in the project.

When the application starts, you should see messages from JRebel, a-la "JRebel: Directory  will be monitored".

That's it. You can just make changes to the code and refresh the app in browser window.